# Given the approximation of $\bar{X}$, find the approximation of $\bar{X}^3$

Tags: statistics

We know that $\bar{X}$ is approximately $N(μ,\frac{σ^2}n)$ for large n. Find the approximate distribution of $u(\bar{X}) = \bar{X}^3$, provided that $μ\neq0$.

How do you go from $\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}\sigma \sim N(0,1)$ to $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu) \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

Comment: please look up Delta Method, try using it and come back if you still have a question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method

Comment: Okay, just one question, how do you go from $\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}\sigma \sim N(0,1)$ to $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu) \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

Comment: @angelo086 use [mgf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Linear_combination_of_independent_random_variables)? I mean, in the first place what does it mean for a random variable to be distributed $N(0,1)$? We are given that $M_Z(z) = e^{t^2/2}$ What is $M_{\sigma Z}(z)$ then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your question $\sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}\sigma \sim N(0,1) \iff \sqrt{n}( \overline{X} - \mu) \sim \sigma N(0,1) \iff \sqrt{n}(\overline{X} - \mu) \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Now, on to the main problem. Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. From CLT, we know $\sqrt{n}\left( \dfrac{\overline{X}-\mu}\sigma\right) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$; i.e. $\overline{X} \stackrel{asymp.}{\sim} N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$.

The Delta method tells us that
$$
\sqrt{n}([\overline{X}]^3 - \mu^3) \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma^2 [3 \mu^2]^2 ) = N(0,(3 \sigma \mu^2)^2)
$$
so that 
$$
\sqrt{n} \dfrac{([\overline{X}]^3 - \mu^3)}{3 \sigma \mu^2} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)
$$
which means
$(\overline{X})^3 \stackrel{asymp.}{\sim} N(\mu^3, (3 \sigma \mu^2)^2 / n)$.

Comment: nice and clear, +1